# How to inject one POJO object to another POJO using spring annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I've created a pojo class A(which is basically neither a service nor repository) and I want to inject it to another pojo class B, and this pojo class B I'll inject to a service class later.
Can you tell me what annotation should I mark to class A, so that it will be treated as spring bean and it could be autowired to class B

I know one annotation @Component but I'm not sure if this would be good practice to use this annotation in spring boot.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Component` is the base annotation and it's perfectly fine to use it.

`@Service` is only as specialization without any behavior and `@Repository` is used for Data access and `@Controller` for web.